# changing text of one textbox when written in other

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

is it possible that when nepali date is inserted on one textbox will be changed into eng date and be seen on other text box without refreshing any page?

i have a function on PHP that changes nep date to eng and vice-versa i just want that to be run on the particular textbox when anyone inserts nepali date on other textbox

i call my function for changing date is

PHP Functions

```
NepToEng()

EngToNep()
```

HTML Elements

```
<input type="text" name="dobnep" size="26" maxlength="300" />

<input type="text" name="empdobeng" size="26" maxlength="300" />
```

Scenario :

when anyone writes nepali date of birth on dobnep will be converted into english and be shown on empdobeng

Answer (score 2):

```
var input1 = $('[name="dobnep"]'),
    input2 = $('[name="empdobeng"]');

input1.on('keyup', function() {
    NepToEng(this.value).done(function(data) {
        input2.val( data );
    });
});

input2.on('keyup', function() {
    EngToNep(this.value).done(function(data) {
        input2.val( data );
    });
});

function NepToEng(val) {
    return $.ajax({
       url : 'link/to/script_that_converts_to_eng.php'
       data: {date: val}
    });
}

function EngToNep(val) {
    return $.ajax({
       url : 'link/to/script_that_converts_to_nep.php'
       data: {date: val}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest reimplementing those functions in Javascript, otherwise you could be making a lot of HTTP requests to your server and degrading the performance of your application for what I imagine is a simple calculation that a browser could handle very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

PHP functions cannot be executed based on user actions. One solution is to use Ajax function that sends the value of dobnep and retrieves its empdobeng in english.

Answer (score 0):

there you go...if you have the entire functionality ready,You just need a little bit of ajax magic in your code.
fetch the value of your engDATE(lets say FETCHED_VALUE) and in responsetext of ajax put this code,

```
document.getElementById(id).value="FETCHED_VALUE"
```

note:allot an id for the text box with name=empdobeng and use function keyup

Answer (score 0):

this was my code and it helped me... which i mixed

**Javascript**

```
function add() {
num1=$("#dobnep").val();
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "change.php",
  data: "dobnep="+num1,
  success: function(html){ 
    document.getElementById('empdobeng').value=html;
  }
 })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="dobnep" id="dobnep" onblur="add()" size="26" maxlength="300" />
<input type="text" name="empdobeng" id="empdobeng" size="26" maxlength="300" />
```

**PHP**

```
$date=UTF8toEng($_POST['dobnep']);

echo EngtoUTF8(NepToEng($date));
```